# Can I avoid or restrict to push the Native fills for certain ads which is served from DFP_DS or Admob they not relevant to our app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, ads, google-dfp

I need to know can I able to avoid or restrict to push the Native fills for certain ads which are served from DFP_DS or Admob if they are not relevant to our app on iOS.

For say, I am getting the amazon music ads and I am not interested to show certain ads in our app. How can I restrict this to fill in the app.

I am getting this in the release mode as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a blocklist from your adnetwork / adserver user interface based on the category, the advertiser or other criterias, as detailled [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3150235?hl=en).